# NSSpeechSynthesizer Change the language

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm writing a simple program based in an example of a Cocoa Book that uses a NSSpeechSynthesizer to speak phrases. I would like to know how can I change the language used to synthesize the phase.

```
#import "PHAppDelegate.h"

@implementation PHAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize textField = _textField;

- (id)init{

    self = [super init];

    if(self){

        NSLog(@"init");

        _speechSynth = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] initWithVoice:nil];

    }

        return self;

}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

- (IBAction)stopIt:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"stoppping");
    [_speechSynth stopSpeaking];

}

- (IBAction)sayit:(id)sender {

    NSString *string = [_textField stringValue];

    if([string length] == 0){

        NSLog(@"There is no text to speech.");

        return;
    }

    NSString *voiceID =[[NSSpeechSynthesizer availableVoices] objectAtIndex:10];

    [_speechSynth setVoice:voiceID];

    [_speechSynth startSpeakingString:string];


    NSLog(@"Have started to say: %@", string);


}
@end
```

This code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (NSString *voiceIdentifierString in [NSSpeechSynthesizer availableVoices]) {
    NSString *voiceLocaleIdentifier = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer attributesForVoice:voiceIdentifierString] objectForKey:NSVoiceLocaleIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"%@ speaks %@", voiceIdentifierString, voiceLocaleIdentifier);
```

}

See [Voice Attributes Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechSynthesizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Voice_Attributes_Keys)

Answer (score 0):

[this 2014 document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsspeechsynthesizer_Class/NSSpeechSynthesizer_Class.pdf) says that there is only one language available (US English).

```
NSVoiceLanguage
The language of the voice (currently US English only). An NSString Deprecated: Use NSVoiceLocaleIdentifier (page 24) instead. Available in OS X v10.0 and later.
Deprecated in OS X v10.5.
Declared in NSSpeechSynthesizer.h.
```

Comment: // NSVoiceLanguage has been replaced by NSVoiceLocaleIdentifier
APPKIT_EXTERN NSVoiceAttributeKey const NSVoiceLanguage API_DEPRECATED("", macos(10.0,10.5));