# Where are the reference strings for NSVoiceLocaleIdentifier?

Tags: swift, macos

I'd like to do text to voice on OSX with Swift where the voice is speaking in a different language than preferences set for the system. I believe the correct way to do this is to use NSVoiceLocaleIdentifier. I see this in the [API documentation](http://en2zh.com/docs/apple/1608/reference/appkit/nsvoicelocaleidentifier?language=objc):

> **NSVoiceLocaleIdentifier**
>
> The language of the voice. An NSString
>
> **Declaration**
>
> NSString *const NSVoiceLocaleIdentifier;
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The canonical locale identifier string describing the
> voice's locale. A locale is generally composed of three pieces of
> ordered information: a language code, a region code, and a variant
> code. Refer to documentation about the NSLocale class or
> Internationalization and Localization Guide for more information.

I have combed through the links for documentation about the NSLocale class and Internationalization and Localization Guides, downloaded sample code, etc. but I still haven't found a reference for what those NSStrings look like. Does anybody know what those language, region, and variant codes are and how they're formatted?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think what you want to do is look at the `availableVoices` and examine their voice attributes: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizer/1668891-voice_attributes_keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stitching together a few things--first credit where credit is due, thanks to [Eric Aya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227743/eric-aya) for explaining how to get an [Xcode playground to do speech synthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965698/how-to-convert-text-to-speech-for-osx-in-swift-playground), [George Warner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445215/geowar) for [sample code printing out the available voices and locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368516/nsspeechsynthesizer-change-the-language), and of course [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) in the comment above who oriented me to a working path. Unless I have this very wrong, it would appear that various voices are oriented around specific languages. So I believe you set the voice for the location.

Here's a setup for an Xcode playground:

```
import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Here's how to get a voice speaking in Spanish:

```
let synth = NSSpeechSynthesizer()
synth.setVoice( "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.paulina.premium" )
synth.startSpeaking( "Hola Mundo mañana" )
```

How did I know that com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.paulina.premium spoke in Spanish?

```
for voiceIdentifierString: String in NSSpeechSynthesizer.availableVoices() {
    var voiceLocaleIdentifier = ( NSSpeechSynthesizer.attributes( forVoice: voiceIdentifierString )[ NSVoiceLocaleIdentifier ] as! String )
    print( "\(voiceIdentifierString) speaks \(voiceLocaleIdentifier)" )
}
```

If I'm wrong in my assumptions, *please* correct me. I'm posting this for anyone who may encounter a similar need.